What is the primary Nginx directory AND where is it declared?
I see in main configuration file relative path which should be included.
Like
..
include file.conf;
..

How it relative path would interpreted to absolute?
According to the directory where main configuration file is or there's any another declared "main" path and such way the result path would be "main"/file.conf?

for debian the relative starts in /etc/nginx

It's a compile time option. You can use nginx -V to see all the compile time options used to generate your nginx binary. I think the one you are looking for is --prefix.

@RichardSmith
No, I think it's only --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf cause included file inside there.
dirname $(nginx -V 2>&1 | grep -o '\-\-conf-path=\(.*conf\)' | cut -d '=' -f2)

my comment is moderating the above comments: there are complie time options which determine where nginx.conf is located, it is not only in /etc/nginx, particularly with other distro's and other pure Nginx (not forked) solutions such as OpenResty which places nginx.conf in /usr/opt/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf...

simple answer is that file.conf is relative to nginx.conf file from which it is called, such that if nginx.conf is located at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf then /etc/nginx/file.conf needs to exist to be included.
Please note that for Nginx there are many possible locations for the nginx.conf file itself depending on the Platform, Linux Distro, compile-time options when compiled from Source, etc.
